# Add to a "null" list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to add an item to a list of card objects, and I get a nullpointer exception if I run this code. I believe I can't add to a 'null' list, but how do I fix this? (The error occurs at 'cards.add(...);')

```
public class Deck {

    private List<Card> cards;
    public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++){
                cards.add(new Card(ranks[i], suits[j], values[i]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have declared `cards` as a reference to a `List`, but you have not assigned it to refer to any actual object.  It looks like you want to create an appropriate object and assign a reference to it, maybe: `cards = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: you never initialized `cards`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your list...

```
private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing that but must have used the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the List cards as follows with the specified element type:

```
private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Comment: from Java 7 diamond operator <> was introduced to add type inference and reduce verbosity:  new ArrayList<>();